# How to use Class<? extends Something>?

Tags: java

`SolrServer.java` have "add()" methods. But, "server.add()"  is failed. is If I use as follows:

in my abstract class:

```
public abstract void addDocs( Class<?  extends SolrServer> server ) throws IOException, SolrServerException;
```

in my Implementataon class:

```
@Override
    public void addDocs(Class<? extends SolrServer> server) throws IOException, SolrServerException {
        ...
        server.add(doc);        
    }
```

[image]

No problem, If I use as follows:

```
@Override
    public void addDocs(SolrServer server) throws IOException, SolrServerException {
       ...    
       server.add(doc);        
    }
```

[image]

What is wrong?

**UPDATE:**

`SolrServer.java` is an abstact class. For this reason, the problem could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) if you just use this:

```
public void addDocs(SolrServer server) throws IOException, SolrServerException {
    ...
    server.add(doc);        
}
```

you should be able to call this method with any Sub-class of SolrServer as well

b) you could also define a Type Variable:

```
public <S extends SolrServer> void addDocs(S server) throws AllKindsOfStuff{
    ...
    server.add(doc);        
}
```

However, you are trying to operate on classes, not on Objects. Change the parameter type from `Class<? extends SolrServer>` to `SolrServer` and you should be fine

Ok, since you have a base class, declare the Type Variable in that base class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<S extends SolrServer>{
    public abstract void addDocs(S server);
}

public class ImplementingClass extends BaseClass<SomeSolrServer>{
    public void addDocs(SomeSolrServer server){
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Your way is good, but it isn't defined in my abstact class as follow( public abstract void <S  extends SolrServer> addDocs( S server ) throws IOException, SolrServerException;  )

Answer (score 1):

The latter is what you want.

Objects of type `Class<T>` are the class themselves; you use them when you want to pass a class to a method, as opposed to an object of that class.

It is permissible in Java to pass a subclass of T for a parameter of type T.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void addDocs(Class<? extends SolrServer> server) throws IOException, SolrServerException {
        ...
        server.add(doc);        
    }
```

The type of the parameter to `server.add()` is `? extends SolrServere` - an unknown subtype of `SolrServer`. Since we don't know what type it is, we don't know if it is a *supertype* of the Class (as you didn't define it let us assume it is `Z`) of instance *doc*; it might or might not be such a *supertype*, so it isn't safe to pass a `Z` there.

Answer (score 0):

Your working method takes an instance of `SolrServer` as argument. And `SolrServer` has a method `add()` taking the type of your doc variable as argument. You can pass an instance of `SolrServer` (or of any subclass of `SolrServer`) as argument to this method.

Your non-working method takes a `java.lang.Class` as argument. And java.lang.Class doesn't have any `add()` method.

Not sure what you're trying to achieve with this method.